# NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_INPUT Error while trying to read local .txt file using xul

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

I am trying to read a locally stored text file in windows xp using xul program below:

```
function read_text_file(file_path)
{
  var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile); 
  file.initWithPath(file_path); 
  var data = "";   
  var fstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);   
  var cstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterInputStream);   
  fstream.init(file, -1, 0, 0);
  cstream.init(fstream, "UTF-8", 0, 0); // you can use another encoding here if you wish   

  let (str = {}) {   
  let read = 0;   
  do {
      read = cstream.readString(0xffffffff, str); // read as much as we can and put it in str.value   
      data += str.value;   
     } 
  while (read != 0);
  }
  cstream.close(); // this closes fstream
  return data;
}
```

But getting Error in **read = cstream.readString(0xffffffff, str);**:

```
Error: NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_INPUT: Component returned failure code: 0x8050000e (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_INPUT) [nsIConverterInputStream.readString]
Source File: chrome://quicknote/content/overlay.js
Line: 168
```

[here I found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm) some description here, but it didn't help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is that the data in that file is not in fact encoded in UTF-8, so trying to decode as UTF-8 ends up throwing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using endoding UTF-16LE, which was causing this error. I just replace UTF-8 to UTF-16LE in my program and it runs good now.

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer: [Reading textual data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Reading_textual_data)